# get integer from html form

Tags: python, html

I want to get the integer value from HTML form and I used the following python code:

```
    form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    if not form.has_key("id"):
        error_pop("There is no id in this form","The format of the request is not correct")
    id = form["id"].value    (*)
```

And in the HTML file, I make the input type as `number`:

```
id: <input type="number" name="id" /><br />
```

However, it seems that the id I get from line (`*`) is still a string.

How can I convert it to integer?

I tried use `int(form["id"].value)`, but python gave me the following error:

> `<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>`: %d format: a number is required, not str args = ('%d format: a number is required, not str',) message = '%d format: a number is required, not str'

So, I gave up using `int()`.

If I try to print the value before parsing it to `int()`, then I will get the internal server error from the browser. Actually I'm always getting this error if I change something in the python file. I can see the error from the error_log.log:

```
/usr/lib/python2.6/cgitb.py:173: DeprecationWarning: BaseException.message has been deprecated as of Python 2.6
value = pydoc.html.repr(getattr(evalue, name))
```

Actually if I grep today's time from error.log, then it cannot show the current error..although it really exits some error that happens several hours ago...

I found something new: only if things involves the "id" thing, the internal server error will appear. If I do something like `id = form["idid"].value`, then it will give the error:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' 
      args = ("int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'",) 
      message = "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Could you post the errors you get?

Comment: @Littm,You mean the error from int(form["id"].value)? There are hundreds lines of errors though...

Comment: The errors you mentioned: `but python gave me tons of errors that I cannot read` ?

Comment: @Littm, Ha, I found that the hundreds lines of errors are given because I don't execute the python file with right permission, after add sudo python xx.py, it works. But the string problem still remains. The error returned from web browser side is:            <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: %d format: a number is required, not str 
 args = ('%d format: a number is required, not str',) 
 message = '%d format: a number is required, not str'

Comment: @Littm, if I add int(form["id"].value), then the server will return internal server error..

Comment: Are you sure that your value is defined? Did you try printing it before, without parsing it to `int`?

Comment: @Littm, Yes..If I print the id before parsing it to `int()`, I will also get internal server error without any specific information. However if I run it in the terminal side by `sudo python xx.py`, then it gives no error except no input. Really don't know how to deal with it right now..

Comment: Can you try using `form.getvalue("id")`, rather than `form['id'].value` and convert that to int using `int()`?

Comment: @favoretti, I tried making this change but I still get the internal server error, actually I think no matter what I change, it will give me this "internal server error"..

Comment: You sure your internal server error is even related to this line? :)

Comment: Another question.. does error_pop() abort your execution cycle, or just prints the message? Cause if it just prints, your form['id'].value will still get executed even if there's no value in the form and will probably fail miserably.

Comment: @favoretti, I checked the error_pop() and it will abort the execution cycle by a sys.exit() call. I'm not sure whether the internal server error is related to this file or not but if I change the file into exactly "photoid = form["id"].value then it will just give the string and integer error, not the internal server error...

Comment: Can you please run `type(form["id"].value)` or print it

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem you were, not being able to convert values from a form to numbers. Here's another solution I adapted from [this blog post](http://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html). I have some values returned from radio buttons sets named q1, q2, q3, etc., and convert them using this dictionary.

```
 str2num = {"1":1, "2":2, "3":3, "4":4, "5":5, "6":6}

 val1 = str2num[ form.getvalue("q1") ]
 val2 = str2num[ form.getvalue("q2") ]
 val3 = str2num[ form.getvalue("q3") ]
```

The value of the form element "q1" was the string form of the digit, so this converts it to to the numerical form. Like you, `int( form.getvalue("q1") )` just wasn't working. I still don't know why this does.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the value of the element is `form`, that you pass to `int` is the error message returned from the http server:
 "%d format: a number is required, not str"
For the sake of argument can you try the same thing without restricting the **id** field to type="number", but type="text". My guess is that this will allow the conversion to integer.
And if you need to enforce the result to be integer, use something like

```
while not id:
  try:
    id = int(form["id"].value)
  except TypeError:
    error_pop("id should be number")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to make it by adding some additional things to it. Firstly I make `id` a text field instead of a number, then I used to regular expression to search for the pattern:`m = re.search("^(?P<x>[-\d]+)$", id);` Then I convert it to integer by: `id = int(m.group('x'));` It somehow works and doesn't give me internal server error. I don't know the reason of previous internal server error and why cannot use number field directly though...